# Pandas Attribute Error in standalone app

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a `Python 3` standalone mac app and I'm using `py2app`. The code works absolutely fine when I run it on my computer. However, when making it self-contained, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas._libs.hashtable' has no attribute 'HashTable'
```

I upgraded `numpy` and `pandas` but I still get the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon your question after finding myself with the same problem. The py2app setup.py script successfully produced an .app file, but running the program from the terminal (`/path/to/app/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`) produced the same attribute error.

I was able to successfully bundle and execute my application by deprecating pandas to an earlier version (0.19.2):

```
pip3 uninstall pandas
pip3 install pandas==0.19.2
```

I should note that I am also using a deprecated version of scipy - 0.14.0.

This is not an ideal solution, but may allow you to produce a successful build. I will update this answer if I find a solution that allows me to use the newest version of pandas (0.20.3)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought I'd never solve it. I'll try it later.